# Who is the most powerful user of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

I just saw a [commercial for the new Star Wars game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLZTACMuMBU) where Starkiller vaporized an entire platoon of stormtroopers with a single energy blast or something.

**What are the effective limits on the Force and who is its most powerful user within both the accepted canon and Legends?**

Comment: Are you interested in raw power alone or do you factor in control?

Comment: There are super-foce-powered "beings", what about Abeloth?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

G-canon answer:

If you go by canon's theory that midi-chlorian counts are The Thing:

- Anakin Skywalker (over 20,000 per cell; source: *Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace*)
- Luke Skywalker ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_%28Star_Wars%29#The_Chosen_One): "Lucas has said in interviews that Luke Skywalker had the same total midi-chlorian count that Anakin did at birth")

Comment: I am wondering does the midichlorian count as the single factor in force power? Maybe  there are other contributing factors to a jedi's powers.

Comment: @Sinan - training.

Comment: @DVK so it could be argued that although Yoda (or Palpatine) has less midichlorian count he has more training (and experience) so they are more powerful.

Comment: @Sinan - depending on your semantics, possibly. No canon answer for that

Comment: Well, if we're going by raw power, didn't Luke Skywalker say that Kyp Durron had more raw power than he did?

Comment: @El'endia - depends on which canon you want. Books are not G-canon.

Comment: @DVK: I'd consider midi-count to be a representation of potential, whereas Sinan is talking about the actual power realized by an individual.

Comment: Do we even know midichlorian counts for non-Skywalkers?

Comment: If we consider raw output power, isn't the StarForge the single most powerful user of the force?  Or is this question really meant for human-sized users?http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Forge

Comment: @SteveED - Is Star Forge alive?

Comment: @DVK - it's described as "semi-living" but I don't remember anything more than that.

Comment: @SteveED - if ya got a proper quote, that's definitely worth an asnwer.

Comment: Hm, that makes me think of [Zonama Sekot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zonama_Sekot). I think it was left open wether it use the Force as the Jedi know it, but it certainly is connected (and powerful).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, at all. It has good information for two Force users, but no comparison. The max in a sample size of 1 is also the min.

Comment: @Matt - It has good information about one Jedi (Anakin) and an unsourced assertion about another (Luke).

Comment: Yes, but it's still only one datapoint. If for example (and this is an exaggeration, of course) the average midiclorean count is really around 100,000, then it would make Anakin's (and thereby Luke's) FAR from exceptional. Without context, a single datapoint is useless. We need some way to know whether or not 20,000 is the highest the universe. Was Yoda's higher? What was Emperor Vitiate's count? Darth Plagueis'? -> One data point is a bad answer.

Answer (score 24):

**THE FATHER**

["The Ones"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ones) were the most powerful Force wielders ever.
["The Father"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) is clearly the most powerful in the Force.

"The Father" kept "The Son" and "The Daughter" at bay, and made sure there was balance in the Force.

"The Father" also made sure the that Abeloth didn't destroy or ruin the universe.

Entire religions were spawned after "The Ones."

They've also been around the longest going back to 1,000,000 BBY.

In the Star Wars Universe nobody was more powerful in the Force than "The Father" as he kept things in order for all that time and had a huge responsibility, without him things would have fallen apart.

Since you included "Force entity" in your question, this is a clear cut answer.

The Clone Wars "Overlords":

> The Father: You cannot imagine what pain it is to have such love for
>   your children and realize that they could tear the very fabric of our
>   universe.
>
> AS: I don't understand.
>
> The Father: It is only here that I can control them. A family in
>   balance. The light and the dark. Day with night. Destruction replaced
>   by creation.
>
> AS: Then why reveal yourselves to us? There are some who would like to
>   exploit our power. The Sith are but one.
>
> The Father: Too much dark or light would be **the undoing of life as you
>   understand it.**

[image]

So the guy keeping "life as you understand it" together and holding the Force in the balance for over a million years is definitely the most powerful Force wielder ever.

I can include more quotes, but clearly The Father is the most powerful Force wielder. After him come The Son, The Daughter, and Abeloth. These beings are stronger in the Force than multiple Jedi or Sith combined.

Comment: Also note the Father's comment that "My children and I can manipulate the Force like no other, therefore, it was necessary to withdraw from the temporal world and live here as anchorites."

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: In recognition that the latest changes to the canon haven't invalidated this answer I've awarded a bounty. The Father is quite definitively the most powerful user of the Force in both the main canon *and* the EU

Answer (score 22):

The Sith Emperor. I just read *Star Wars: The Old Republic: Revan*, and I have to say he is the most powerful. Before the age of 10, he killed his mother and foster-father and by 10 took over his planet and forced his biological father to flee.

At 13, he gained the attention of Marka Ragnos and quickly became a Sith Lord. He created the Sith Empire, destroyed 9 members of the sith council at once. He bent Revan and Malak to the dark side, made himself immortal, and possibly unleashed the most perverse force technique to date- completely "ate" his homeworld of Nathema, turning it into a place completely devoid of the Force.

Yeah, he's number 1.

Comment: Impressive.  Who was his master?

Comment: @Iterator Darth Lucas himself?

Comment: I think you are mistaken in one thing. He did not take over the planet. He caused all live to die there and feed on that.

Comment: None of that is canon tho'. You could say Jar Jar with just as much validity.

Comment: @Gaius Except Jar Jar is obviously portrayed as being easily susceptible to Sith mind tricks, there's no way he's even in the running.

Comment: They made him a General nonetheless.

Comment: Don't forget the fact he "ate" the planet!

Answer (score 17):

[The Father](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) from the *Clone Wars* series is a hot candidate. It is not entirely clear whether Anakin is stronger in raw power but Father and his offspring sure do things I am rather sure are unique.

In general, the question may be ill-posed. There are multiple examples of Jedi being stronger than others in some areas but weaker in others. A prominent example would be [Corran Horn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corran_Horn) who is useless at telekinesis but has the rare talent to absorb raw energy.

Comment: Not just from the clone wars....also from the new Jedi order

Answer (score 16):

**TL;DR: In current Disney canon, the strongest single Force user would be Luke Skywalker. Across all canon levels, the strongest single user would likely be Abeloth.**

---

It should first be noted that Force abilities & power fluctuate depending on the medium. In the comics & video games, we have seen displays of power that absolutely blow away anything we've seen in the films or Clone Wars series. That said, I'll break the answer up into two sections - the current (Disney) canon level, and the Legends/Everything level.

### Disney Canon

As of August 2015 (we still haven't seen the new trilogy yet), the single most powerful Force user in existence is [**Luke Skywalker**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker). Luke possesses all of the raw talent & power that his father [Anakin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) did, and Anakin was believed by [Mortis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) to be the most powerful user of the Force to ever exist.

After becoming Darth Vader, Anakin found his abilities "capped" by his alterations. Luke, however, is not as limited by a loss of body mass like his father was, and therefore should be capable of reaching nearly his maximum potential - a potential that would rival or exceed anything we saw from Anakin. Whether or not we will see this potential on-screen remains to be seen, but is quite possible as an older Luke appears in the new trilogy coming up.

[image]

Other contenders would be:

- [Mortis (The Father)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)); originally a mortal man, he became the avatar of The Balance between the light & dark sides of The Force.
- [The Son](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Son); mortal who became the avatar of the Dark Side.
- [The Daughter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Daughter); mortal who became the avatar of the Light Side.

### Legends Canon

If we look at the entire SW universe - the Legends continuity, games, everything - then we find a plethora of candidates. The most likely contender, however, would be [**Abeloth**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Abeloth). Known as The Mother, Abeloth's power seems to exceed that of even Mortis since it took both Mortis AND his children to imprison her. Even in a very weakened state, she faced off against numerous Jedi and Sith (often several at a time) yet consistently held her own, and the Force itself seems to be at her beck & call. She also had the ability to manipulate and outright control others, as well as cast illusions across an entire planet (not to mention hiding her rather gruesome appearance).

[image]

- [Naga Sadow](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Naga_Sadow); used the Force to destroy the entire [Denarii System](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Denarii_Nova). May also be the first known user of [Battle Meditation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_meditation).
- [Darth Nihilus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Nihilus); learned to "feed" off the Force energy of entire planets.
- [The Sith Emperor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_Emperor); used the Force to extend his own life by centuries.
- [Emperor Palpatine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Palpatine); cheated death numerous times by changing bodies, and also used battle meditation extensively across the entire Empire.
- [Galen Marek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galen_Marek); possessed a natural affinity for the Force and disarmed Darth Vader at the age of 6. Also used the Force to crash an Imperial Star Destroyer from orbit.
- [Dorsk 81](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dorsk_81); focused the energy of several Jedi & telekinetically "pushed" an entire fleet of Imperial vessels out of the Yavin system. Died from the effort, however.

Comment: "Luke, however, is not limited by a loss of body mass like his father was, and therefore should be capable of reaching his maximum potential" -- not quite maximum, probably. He *did* lose a hand himself.

Comment: "Luke possesses all of the raw talent & power that his father Anakin did" -- where in Disney canon has this been stated? Also, you mention Mortis, but why aren't you counting the Father on Mortis as a Force-user more powerful than Anakin? Anakin can't hold back lightsabers the way the Father could...

Comment: @Hypnosifl - actually, that's something that Lucas himself has confirmed. Luke is basically Anakin 2.0 in Lucas' view. And the Father believed Anakin to be potentially his equal power-wise. Presumably Father would have trained Anakin further if he had accepted the proposal to replace him.

Comment: Do we know if Anakin was (either potentially or actually) more powerful than The Father? I believe the one time Anakin attempted to challenge The Father, The Father won rather easily.

Comment: @Ellesedil - yes, Father was more concerned with Anakin's potential than his current level of power. Father seemed to believe that Anakin would be able to replace him, so presumably that would involve training or a transfer of ability of some kind.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, that doesn't make it clear to me if Anakin was less powerful, more powerful, or as powerful (potentially) as the Father. The only thing that seems clear is that Anakin was more powerful than the Son and Daughter.

Comment: @Ellesedil - few months late, but I agree. Added Mortis and his children to the Disney Canon section. Not sure about the kids, but felt I should include them since they're more powerful than some of the others I list in Legends canon.

Comment: "And therefore should be capable of reaching nearly his maximum potential - a potential that would rival or exceed anything we saw from Anakin" this is a lot of "ifs" for starters Luke doesn't have the training, nor the teachers, nor the motivation, nor the environment to reach full potential. I would be amazed he wouldn't fall into a comfort zone as being by the end of Ep VI the most powerful Force user alive.

Answer (score 10):

[Abeloth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Abeloth) known as the bringer of chaos and an entity of the Force.  It required the combined powers of 3 Celestial beings and an ancient race of builders to imprison her and she has the power to exist in multiple forms on multiple planets simultaneously.  She is by far the most powerful being that exists in the EU.

The [Celestials](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial) are probably number 2.

[Zenoma Sekot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zonama_Sekot) is probably number 3.  An entire planet with the power to use the Force.

Answer (score 2):

[Darth Nihilus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Nihilus)

I believe he is the strongest user of the Force. His power and hatred is so strong he corrupts himself with his own Force, sucking it out of others and feeding constantly on the energy around him. His body completely became a pit of pure dark energy and Force that he had to seal his soul in his robes and mask. Its even told that he devoured an entire Force enriched planet to nothing, taking all its life energy and Force to feed himself. The more Force he fed off of and used, the more his hunger grew for more. He goal was to take the Force out of everything in the galaxy and supposedly bring "balance".

Comment: @Matematicos sorry really new to this website. i tried putting the link in the "Darth Nihilus" part up top but i guess it didn't work :c

Comment: @phantom42 thanks for editing it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly Galen Marek. Not the clone, the one who died saving the rebel leaders. When he was 6 he could already Force-pull the saber outta Vader's hand, and he didn't even know about Force yet. And during the fight with Shaak-ti he freaking tased the giant pit of tentacle thingy half dead, and he was only 16 or something. Then he stopped a freaking star-destroyer on its path after he defeated a staff-guard and a whole station full of troopers, and those staff-guards are either Sith lord or Jedi master used-to-be or Revan himself (it was in the novel). He even defeats Darth Vader, and the Emperor. If he went ahead and killed the Emperor, then he won't be dead because of the Emperor's stealth-attack-with-critical-damage. Even so, he still took the full blast of Emperor's lighting for about half a minute, and detonating the Force, blowing one-fifth of the Death Star's surface to trash. On Wookieepedia, Luke is said to be the overall most powerful Force-user, but also that Galen would took his place if he did not die at the age of 18.

Answer (score -2):

Even though Darth Vader apparently had a huge midichlorian count, he didn't wield the Force as skilfully as Palpatine (a.k.a the Emperor) who stayed in the shadows and ripped apart the galaxy with his Machiavellian manipulations and treason. He built a vast army of cloned stormtroopers and converted the Republic into the evil Empire in a similar way to Hitler, eventually resulting in genocide and the destruction of worlds. It seems likely all the time he was doing this he was using his Force powers to persuade, manipulate and disappear those who stood in his way. That is the true power of the Dark Side. By comparison what did Darth Vader actually achieve with his powers? Sure he stopped a blaster bolt with his hand. Choked a few guys.

Comment: So what's the actual answer here? Are you saying Palpatine was the most powerful Force user?

Comment: I am saying that it's Palpatine.