# Who is the most influential Sith? (Canon and EU acceptable)

Tags: star-wars, the-force, sith

This question is something of a companion [to this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/who-is-the-most-powerful-user-of-the-force-in-star-wars-canon/51973#51973). I am interested in finding out who the most influential Sith (or other Force entity) was in the Star Wars universe? *Influence* is not the same thing as *raw power* - regardless of personal abilities, which individual had the broadest and longest overall effect on the Galaxy?

Comment: [This guy](http://tubulamarok.free.fr/starwars/sw6.2004-palpatine.gif), perhaps?

Comment: Without a solid definition of "influence", this question borders heavily on soliciting opinion-based answers.

Comment: Influential how? Palpatine effectively took over the entire galaxy and had the most political influence. Darth Bane set the course for the rules of the Sith, arguably making him the most influential over the Sith order. Anakin killed the emperor, arguably making him the most influential as he overthrew the Sith's control.

Comment: You did say Sith or other Force entity. If you include all force entities I think there's a simple answer. I'll post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THE FATHER**

"The Ones" (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ones) were the most powerful force wielders ever. "The Father" (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) in additional to be the most powerful in the force was the most influential.

"The Father" kept "The Son" and "The Daughter" at bay, and made sure there was balance in the force.

"The Father" also made sure the that Abeloth didn't destroy or ruin the universe.

Entire religions were spawned after "The Ones."

They've also been around the longest going back to 1,000,000 BBY.

In the Star Wars Universe nobody has influenced the force, or the universe more than "The Father" as he kept things in order for all that time and had a huge responsibility, without him things would have fell apart.

Since you included "force entity" in your question, this is a clear cut answer.

The Clone Wars "Overlords":

> The Father: You cannot imagine what pain it is to have such love for
>   your children and realize that they could tear the very fabric of our
>   universe.
>
> AS: I don't understand.
>
> The Father: It is only here that I can control them A family in
>   balance. The light and the dark. Day with night. Destruction replaced
>   by creation.
>
> AS: Then why reveal yourselves to us? There are some who would like to
>   exploit our power. The sith are but one.
>
> The Father: Too much dark or light would be **the undoing of life as you
>   understand it.**

[image]

So the guy keeping "life as you understand it" together and holding the force in the balance for over a million years is definitely the most influential force wielder ever.

If you're going by just the movies, then "Darth Vader" as he was the most hands on and the stories were most centered around him and his character. You could also choose Palpatine as Richard suggests. Palpatine was a mastermind strategist.

But there wasn't anybody in the series that influenced the universe and for as long a period a time as "The Father" if you're including all force wielders.

Comment: Form you're answer, it's sounds as if The Father was neutral and not a Sith at all. The OP is looking for a Sith.

Comment: @Daft in the description of his question he included "Or other force entity." The father is a force entity. If that is incorrect the OP should pull those words from the question. If he wants to include all force wielders as the questions states, then there is no more influential person in the SWU than The Father(Mortis).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to gauge who was the most influential Sith without a clearer definition of exactly what *influence* is.

But **[Darth Bane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane)** could conceivably be in the running, he created the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two) in an attempt to put an end to all of the in-fighting within the Sith:

> Darth Bane, born under the name of Dessel, was the Sith'ari and the Dark Lord of the Sith responsible for creating the Rule of Two.

[image]

---

Another contender could be **[Darth Andeddu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Andeddu)**, he is beleived to be the first Sith Lord to prefix his name with the title: Darth.

> Darth Andeddu, also referred to as the Immortal God-King of Prakith, was an ancient humanoid male who reigned as Dark Lord of the Sith, and was dubiously thought of as the forebear of the "Darth" title.

[image]