# Was/is Darth Vader the most powerful force user?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader

In this [interview from 1999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpiEk42_O_Q) when asked why Darth Vader is a favorite character among children George Lucas says;

> "... and **who is more power than Darth Vader?** Some will be attracted to
>   Luke Skywalker because he is the good guy, but ultimately we know that
>   Darth Vader is more powerful than he is. As time goes you discover
>   that he more powerful because he is the ultimate father, who is all
>   powerful."

Looking at this question [Who is the most powerful user of the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/who-is-the-most-powerful-user-of-the-force-in-star-wars-canon) there many answers in the primary canon and Legends canon on who that might be.

**Does this quote from Lucas  give us a clear answer that Darth Vader is the most powerful**, or is Lucas' quote being given in the narrow field of Darth Vader vs Luke Skywalker? I understand this George Lucas we are talking about... so there might be a contradiction in another interview or something was ret-conned at a later time!

Also, at the time the interview was given I think the answer would be limited to *Episodes I-VI*. Answers would have to come from G-canon.

Comment: If you feel a question has out of date answers, the appropriate course of action is to raise a bounty on the original question (with a note indicating that [the existing answers are outdated](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UEiSN.png)) rather than creating a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Richard, is there any course of action for when the *question* is outdated? I just feel that while the title  elicits the good answers, the question does no justification to such an in-depth topic.

Comment: I've edited the dupe question and shoved a bounty on it. For the record, I felt that [JMFB's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99439/20774) was already pretty comprehensive, from a canon perspective