# How hard is it for Jedi to use the force

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

How hard is it for the average Jedi to move objects? Like what are their limitations? How hard do they have to concentrate to use it to move a 20 pound rock for example? Legends and Canon allowed.

Comment: This is relatively vague. You'll get better answers if you can focus this to be related to a single jedi and a specific object.

Comment: Seven.  It is seven hard.

Comment: Very. Unless you're good at it, in which case, merely quite.

Comment: If size matters not, why was lifting the Xwing out of the swamp seemingly so taxing?

Comment: I think it was taxing because Yoda was SO OLD.  Just a year before he died.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking the ease in which one can use the force has to do the [midichlorian count](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian).

As we can see in this question and answers the Force users with a higher midichlorian count are shown to be able perform greater feats. [Who is the most powerful user of the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/who-is-the-most-powerful-user-of-the-force)

As with anything, the amount of dedication a single user puts into their training will also be a factor. There seems to be no implied limit on how a Force user can manipulate physical objects.